# Black cross that I didn't add appearing on print layout in QGIS

Tags: qgis, printing

When I went to print my map in QGIS 3.22.8, there is a black cross on my image which I did not add. I thought it might have just been in the print layout, but it persisted when I exported the image. I do not know how to remove it but would like it to be gone when I print my image.

[image]

Comment: I think you should first try to isolate where it comes from. Your layers or something added by the layout properties ? How many layers do you have ? One raster below a vector layer? Hide the vector layer. If raster, what is the raster source, is it tiled ? In the layout , it could be grid options, but in that case it would show the grid above the vector data as well

Comment: When you export the layout to pdf do you still see the cross there? Could just be a rendering issue in the layout view.

Comment: @Kartograaf Yes, when I export the file to PDF it is still there. It does not appear on the map builder side, however.

Comment: @Kasper I only have two layers total, the shape files on top and a Google Satellite basemap. In the exported pictures, the lines appear under the shape files, so I assume it would be on the basemap side, yes?

Comment: @Kasper Weird thing just happened. When I exported directly from QGIS to PDF instead of going to print layout, there is no cross. It's only when I do print layout where I run into this issue.

Comment: Can you provide more details: how did you add Google Satellite, as an XYZ layer ? Any specific layer property, which coordinates you are zooming on, project CRS, layout scale, export ppi etc...

Comment: Just guessing here: In the project properties (3.18.3), under general settings, there is a setting called "Avoid artifacts when project is rendered as map tiles (degrades performance)". Perhaps that's worth a try?

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same issue and once I changed the transparency to 100% for Google imagery the issue went away.